# Explicit value for series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

We consider the sum
$$
\sum_{n_{1},\, n_{2}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\,\,\,
\frac{16}{(2 n_1 - 2 \nu n_2 + 1)^2 (2 n_1 + 2 \nu - 2 \nu n_2 - 1)^2}
$$
with $\nu = (-1)^{1/3}$ and $\mathrm{i}$ is the imaginary unit.

- I am wondering if there is a closed form expression for that double series.
- Notice, that it definitely converges, as the denominator essentially behaves like
  $\left\Vert\,{n}\,\right\Vert^{4}$.

Comment: I very much doubt it. The numerical value is approximately $0.756915+5.49981i$, although the convergence is quite slow.

Comment: what makes you doubt it?

Comment: Since
$$\frac 1 {(z + l)^2 (z + a + l)^2} = \\
\frac 1 {a^2} \left(
 \left( \frac 1 {(z + a + l)^2} - \frac 1 {l^2} \right) +
 \left( \frac 1 {(z + l)^2} - \frac 1 {l^2} \right) \right) + \\
\frac 2 {a^3} \left(
 \left( \frac 1 {z + a + l} - \frac 1 l + \frac {z + a} {l^2} \right) -
 \left( \frac 1 {z + l} - \frac 1 l + \frac z {l^2} \right) \right),$$
the sum reduces to $\wp_L$ and $\zeta_L$, where $L$ is an equianharmonic lattice, for which the required values of $\wp_L$ (which will differ from the given answer because of a wrong factor in $E_6$) and $\zeta_L$ are known.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $L=\Bbb{Z}+e^{2i\pi /3}\Bbb{Z}$, your sum is $f(1/2)$ with
$$f(z)=\sum_{l\in L} \frac1{(z+l)^2(z+l+e^{2i\pi/3}-1)^2}$$
Which is meromorphic $L$-periodic with a pole of order $2$, with $a=e^{2i\pi/3}-1$
[we get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions)  $$f(z)=\frac{2}{a^2}\wp_L(z)+C$$

Next, substracting from $\wp_L'(z)^2-4\wp_L(z)^3$ a sum over its poles to get a bounded entire function, we have $$\wp_L'(z)^2=4\wp_L(z)^3-\frac43 \pi^4 E_4(e^{2i\pi /3}) \wp_L(z)-\frac8{27} \pi^6 E_6(e^{2i\pi /3})$$ where $\frac43 \pi^4 E_4(e^{2i\pi /3}),\frac8{27} \pi^6 E_6(e^{2i\pi/3})$ are given in term of the Laurent coefficients of $\wp_L(z)-z^{-2}$. Because $L=e^{2i\pi /3}L$ we have $E_4(e^{2i\pi /3})=0$. And $\wp_L'(z)$ is odd $L$-periodic thus $\wp_L'(1/2)=\wp_L'(-1/2)=0$.

Whence
$$\wp_L(1/2) =  e^{2i\pi n/3} (\frac14 \frac8{27} \pi^6 E_6(e^{2i\pi /3}))^{1/3}$$ Finally, this is where we need the whole theory of complex tori/elliptic curves/modular forms, $$E_6(e^{2i\pi /3})=(-1728 \Delta(e^{2i\pi/3}))^{1/2}=\pm i 3\sqrt{3} 2^3 (2\pi)^6 \eta(e^{2i\pi/3})^{12}$$ $$= \pm i 3\sqrt{3} 2^3 (2\pi)^6  (e^{-\frac{\pi i}{24}}\frac{\sqrt[8]{3}  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3/2}}{2 \pi })^{12}$$

---

Computation of $C$:

$\sum_m \sum_n$ means $\lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{m=-M}^M \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N$.

From $\sum_n \frac1{(z+\nu^t n)^2}=\nu^{-2t}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi \nu^{-t} z)}$ and the absolute convergence of $\sum_m \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi (\nu^{-t} z+m \nu))}$

then $$g(z)=\sum_{t=0}^2 \sum_m \sum_n \frac1{(z+\nu^t (n+m \nu))^2}+\frac1{(z+\nu^t(n+m \nu)+a)^2}$$ $$=2\sum_{t=0}^2  \sum_m \sum_n \frac1{(z+\nu^t (n+m \nu))^2}$$ $$
=2\sum_m \sum_n \sum_{t=0}^2 \frac1{(z+\nu^t (n+m \nu))^2}-\frac{1_{(n,m)\ne (0,0)}}{(\nu^t (n+m \nu))^2}=6 \wp_L(z)$$

From $\sum_n \frac1{z+n}-\frac1{z+n+b}=\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi z}-1}-\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi (z+b)}-1}$ then
$$h(z)=\sum_{t=0}^2 \sum_m \sum_n \frac1{z+\nu^t (n+m\nu)}-\frac1{z+\nu^t (n+m\nu)+a}$$ $$=\sum_{t=0}^2 \nu^{-t}\sum_m \frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} z+m\nu )}-1}-\frac{2i\pi}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} (z+a)+m\nu )}-1}=2i\pi (\nu^0+\nu^{-1}-2\nu^{-2})=-6i\pi \nu$$
and hence $$3 f(z)=
3\sum_{l\in L} \frac1{a^2 (z+l)^2} - \frac2{a^3 (z+l)} + \frac1{a^2 (a + z+l)^2} + \frac2{a^3 (a + z+l)}$$ $$=\sum_{t=0}^2\sum_{l\in L} \frac1{a^2 (z+\nu^t l)^2} - \frac2{a^3 (z+\nu^t  l)} + \frac1{a^2 (a + z+\nu^t  l)^2} + \frac2{a^3 (a + z+\nu^t  l)}$$ $$=
\frac1{a^2} g(z)-\frac2{a^3} h(z)=\frac6{a^2} \wp_L(z)+\frac2{a^3} 6i\pi \nu$$

Comment: Complex tori, elliptic curves and modular forms is a very deep theory so I can't give much details, just say that this theory solves your question. The hardest part is finding $\eta(e^{2\pi i/3})$ the Dedekind eta function. Proving that for some $a$, $g(z)=f(z)-a \wp_L(z)$ is a bounded entire function thus constant is not too hard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions

Comment: Very nice solution +1.

Comment: We have $f(z) = 2 \wp_L(z)/a^2 + C$ (since $f$ is of order $2$), but $C \neq 0$. The relation between $E_6$ and $\Delta$ should be $\Delta = -(2 \pi)^{12} E_6^2/1728$, so
$$\wp_L {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)} =
\frac {\Gamma^6 {\left( \frac 1 3 \right)}} {2^{8/3} \pi^2},\\
f {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)} =
\frac 2 {a^2} \wp_L {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)} -
 \frac {2 \pi} {3 \sqrt 3} + \frac {2 \pi i} 3.$$

Comment: @Maxim It would be so great if you could explain how you identify this constant $C$

Comment: @reuns do you think Maxim has a point that you are missing a constant?

Comment: @reuns I think the issue is that you choose a particular order of summation and then sum over things that are not absolutely summable.

Comment: @Maxim See my edit, I think your constant is incorrect.

Comment: @Sascha Sure, see my edit I think my method is ok, one more non-zero constant. You can evaluate the series numerically to see if it fits.

Comment: Thanks reuns, it looks similar up to a $2\pi$,will investigate this numerically.

Comment: @reuns So how do you evaluate the sum $\sum_m \frac{1}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} z+m\nu )}-1}-\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} (z+a)+m\nu )}-1}?$

Comment: @Sascha Only two or four terms (depending on $t$) survive in $\sum_{m=-M}^M \frac{1}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} z+m\nu )}-1}-\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi (\nu^{-t} (z+a)+m\nu )}-1}$

Comment: @reuns well, numerically I could not find an agreement and I suspect it is from precisely that series, since it is not convergent as such, it may be the same issue as before...

Comment: @reuns I actually now also checked maxim's result and it seems to be the right one...unfortunately he is does not seem to be willing to share his insights with us...

Comment: @Sascha My mistake, I forgot a $2i\pi$ term. But I'm sure the method is ok !!

Comment: It should be $2 \pi i (\nu^0 + \nu^{-1} - 2 \nu^{-2}) = -6 \pi i \nu$, then your $C$ is the same. Regarding the modular discriminant, there are different conventions, you're using one definition of $\Delta$ in the identity with $E_6$ and another definition in the identity with $\eta$.

Comment: @Maxim What is really wanted is your method, is it more or less the same, or are you making $E_2$ appear then use some identities ?

Comment: Also we can evaluate $g_3(L)$ directly from $\int_0^1 dz = \int_\Gamma \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4x^3+g_3(L)}}=cst.B(1/2,1/3)$ where $\Gamma$ is a certain closed loop in the elliptic curve

Comment: @reuns okay, I still do not believe in it.So this $e^{2\pi i \nu^{-t}a}.$ When $t=0$ it is just $$e^{2\pi i (\nu-1)}=e^{2\pi i \nu}$$ so it can be absorbed in $m.$ by making an index shift $m+1 \mapsto m.$ Similar reasoning applies in all other cases. In particular, we can use that $exp(2\pi i \nu^{-1})=exp(-2\pi i \nu).$

Comment: @Sascha Yes. For $t=2$ it is $m-2\to m$ (because $\nu^{-2}a = -1-2\nu$)

Comment: @reuns yes, but then does this not show that the sums cancel exactly? How do you find these non-zero expressions? I don't quite see the 2 or 4 terms that do not cancel, as you claim.

Comment: @Sascha $\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{m=-M}^M (c_m-c_{m+1}) =\lim_{M\to \infty} c_{-M}-c_{M+1}$. When $t=2$ it is $\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{m=-M}^M (c_m-c_{m+2})$.

Comment: @reuns thanks for this nice discussion...